# SPFx - How to protect and minify my output bundle.js

Tags: javascript, spfx, sharepoint-framework, react, webpack

When i deploy my **solution.sppkg** i want to protect my output bundle js to avoid js injection?

> How to minify bundle.js with gulp task?

[image]

How to do this?

Comment: Refer this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656647/gulp-bundle-then-minify

Answer (score 0):

Use `gulp bundle --ship` and  `gulp package-solution --ship` to minimize your SPFx bundle file.

See this link for more details on packaging your solution for production: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/hosting-webpart-from-office-365-cdn#prepare-web-part-assets-to-deploy